# How to make dev_appserver.py use a sepparate version of python?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-app-engine-python

On a fresh Ubuntu install, I have python 2.7, 3.6 and 3.7.

Running `python --version` gives me 3.7.
I can start dev_appeserver using 2.7 but it seems that it's choosing to use 3.6 inside:

```
INFO     2020-04-12 21:16:19,875 instance_factory.py:121] Detected Python 3.6.9
```

How can I make it use python 3.7?

**Edit**:

A bit more details. So in my `app.yaml` I do have the runtime set correctly to:

```
runtime: python37
```

So in theory the sdk should use python 3.7 inside. Not sure why it's defaulting to 3.6

Trying to call `dev_appserver.py` directly gives an even stranger error:

```
ERROR    2020-04-15 09:19:07,053 sdk_update_checker.py:203] The requested api_version (None) is not supported by the python37 runtime in this release of the SDK. The supported api_versions are ['1'].
```

Answer (score 1):

**Revise installed Python versions**

On a test server in this example Python v2.7 and v3.5 are installed. Shell commands `python`, `python2`, `python3` are just links to the executables `/usr/bin/python2.7` and `/usr/bin/python3.5`.

```
$ python    # type in "python", then press `Tab` 
 python      python2     python2.7   python3     python3.5 

$ which python python2 python2.7 python3 python3.5
 /usr/bin/python 
 /usr/bin/python2 
 /usr/bin/python2.7 
 /usr/bin/python3 
 /usr/bin/python3.5 

$ cd /usr/bin
$ ls -go python python2 python2.7 python3 python3.5
 lrwxrwxrwx 1       9 Jan 24  2017 python -> python2.7 
 lrwxrwxrwx 1       9 Jan 24  2017 python2 -> python2.7 
 -rwxr-xr-x 1 3779512 Nov 24  2017 python2.7 
 lrwxrwxrwx 1       9 Jan 20  2017 python3 -> python3.5 
 -rwxr-xr-x 2 4747120 Jan 19  2017 python3.5
```

**Modify symlinks**

Existing Python symlinks might be redefined as needed, for example:

```
$ cd /usr/bin
$ ls -go python
 lrwxrwxrwx 1 9 Jan 24  2017 python -> python2.7 
$ python -V 
 Python 2.7.13 

$ sudo rm python 
$ sudo ln -s python3.5 python 
$ ls -go python 
 lrwxrwxrwx 1 9 Apr 13 19:08 python -> python3.5 
$ python -V 
 Python 3.5.3
```

**Run Python scripts**

There are two commonly used methods to run Python script in Linux shell:

1. Launch Python script itself without specifying interpreter in the command line;
2. Launch interpreter and pass Python script as a parameter.

**1.** Add a [shebang string](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) at the beginning of the script to specify a certain interpreter. For Python v3 (with redefined symlinks is this example) it could be any of the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
#!/usr/bin/python3
#!/usr/bin/python3.5
```

Then launch the script:

```
$ ./my_script.py
```

**2.** Launch Python v3 executable with a script as a parameter. In this example, any command of those listed below would work:

```
$ python my_script.py
$ python3 my_script.py
$ python3.5 my_script.py
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I don't think it might be applicable in this case. The problem is more specific to how app engine sdk chooses the python runtime than general running python scripts

Comment: This was to illustrate what is under the hood, because basically App Engine is just a kind of abstraction layer or a wrapper around Linux and Python runtime. There is no  magic there. For instance in App Engine Flexible you can define a Docker-based custom runtime environment as you need, and from the Python script execution perspective this will look like a set of modules and executables placed into the right directories, kernel and network interfaces.

Answer (score 0):

dev_appserver.py now supports the --python_virtualenv_path parameter as see [here](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/release-notes#app_engine_20) so that you can point to a python3 version

Comment: Santiago Echavarría Correa, this does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/214173).

Comment: Yeap, better to send these as comments rather than answers, since you are asking a question from the author..

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33645180)